# What to do after installing new m.2 SSD in my laptop with existing HDD of 1 TB?

Tags: windows, ssd, hybrid-storage

My laptop has an extra slot for M.2 SSD and has an existing HDD of 1 TB . My laptop takes about 1-2 minute to boot up and is slow to load applications like chrome . I wanted to know if I will need to re-install Windows on SSD drive to make my app load up and boot up speeds faster . Will I have to reinstall my applications and games on the SSD drive to make them fast ? Or keeping them on the HDD and just installing SSD in the M.2 slot and creating a partition will give me the benefits of SSD ?

Answer (score 0):

The Short Answer is **YES**

you have to install windows on your SSD for making the boot time lesser and to load application faster.

But their are other ways that do not require to reinstall windows and all your apps and games:

- [Clone HHD to SSD](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-disk-without-reinstalling-windows.html)
- [Migrate OS to SSD](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/migrate-os-to-ssd.html)

---

Keeping your apps and games on HDD dose not decrease their loading time (even you have installed windows in SSD), you have to manually move your apps and games to SSD partation or reinstall them in SSD.